# java - BufferedReader readLine stop reading when encouters empty string

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, readline

I am using BufferedReader to read a text file line by line. Then i use a method to normalize each line text. But there is something wrong with my normalization method, after the call to it, BufferedReader object stop reading file. Can someone help me with this.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "";

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            string += normalize(line);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    System.out.println(string);
}

public static String normalize(String string) {

    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(string.trim());



    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if(text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            removeWhiteSpaces(i + 1, text);
        }
    }

    if(text.charAt(text.length() - 1) != '.') {
        text.append('.');
    }

    text.append("\n");
    return text.toString();
}

public static void removeWhiteSpaces(int index, StringBuilder text) {
        int j = index;
        while(text.charAt(j) == ' ') {
            text.deleteCharAt(j);
        }
    }
```

and here is the text file that i use:

```
abc .

 asd.



 dasd.
```

Comment: no exception, just "hangs"!?

Comment: what does "removeWhitespace" do exactly?

Comment: @xerx593 no exception or even hangs. It run normally but only prints out the first line: "abc ."

Comment: @Alan i just edited it.

Comment: Don't just catch `Exception` and do nothing about it. Do a `e.printStackTrace()` at least, otherwise it will just fail silently and you'll never know why.

Comment: You are getting an IndexOutOfBounds in removeWhiteSpaces which you silently catch in your main method.

Comment: `if(text.charAt(text.length() - 1) != '.')` what if text has a length of zero, because you passed a blank line?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have problem in your `removeWhiteSpaces(i + 1, text);`, and if you have problem in the string process, the reader wont able to read the next line.

You don't check the empty string, and you call `text.charAt(text.length()-1)`, it is a problem too.

Print the exception, change your catch block to write out the exception:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The reason is in your `while(text.charAt(j) == ' ') {`, you don't examine the length of StringBuilder, but you delete it...

Answer (score 2):

Try ScanReader

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(is);
 int rowCount = 0;
 while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
             String temp = scan.nextLine();

             if(temp.trim().length()==0){
                 continue;
             }
}
```

//rest of your logic

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.trim().isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }
         string += normalize(line);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The normalize function is causing this.
the following tweak to it shoudl fix this:

```
public static String normalize(String string) {

        if(string.length() < 1) {
            return "";
        }
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(string.trim());
        if(text.length() < 1){
            return "";
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            if(text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                removeWhiteSpaces(i + 1, text);
            }
        }

        if(text.charAt(text.length() - 1) != '.') {
            text.append('.');
        }

        text.append("\n");
        return text.toString();
    }
```

Comment: The string could have a length greater than 1, then trim is called and it would be zero.

Comment: added another if as a fix

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your code but in the understanding of the `readLine()` method. In the documentation is stated:

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

So that means that if the method finds an empty line it will stop reading and return `null`.

The code proposed by @tijn167 would do the workaround using `BufferedReader`. If you are not restraint to `BufferedReader` use `ScanReader` as @Abhishek Soni suggested.

Also, your method `removeWhiteSpaces()` is checking for white spaces while the empty lines are not a white space but a carry return `\r` or a line feed `\n` or both. So your condition `text.charAt(j) == ' '` is never satisfied.

Answer (score -1):

Second line of your file is empty, therefore the while loop stops

Comment: If the line was empty, it would return an empty string but continue until the file is finished. It would not return null, which causes the loop to terminate. The real issue is the swallowed exception that hides any problems.